# SFMC Use AMPScript to see if user is in data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I'm sending to a big list and it has groups of users set up as Data Extensions.  I want to do some dynamic content at time of send based on if the user is in a particular Data Extension.  There is some overlap but I can deal with that with if/else.  I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
%%[ IF UserIsInDataExtension("London_users") THEN ]%%
(Content for London segment)
%%[ ELSEIF UserIsInDataExtension("Birmingham_users")]%$
(Content for Birmingham segment)
%%[ ELSEIF UserIsInDataExtension("Never_purchased")]%%
(Content for Never purchased segment)
%%[ELSE]%%
(default content)
%%[ END ]%%
```

Is there something like this in AMPScript , and if there's nothing exactly like this then can I do something which attempts a lookup from the Data Extension as a way of seeing if the user is in it?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your best bet might be to use the [Lookup()](https://ampscript.guide/book/lookup) AMPScript function.  For example:

```
%%[

var @lookupEmailAddress 
set @lookupEmailAddress = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
set @InLondonUsers = Lookup("London_users", "emailAddress", "emailAddress", @lookupEmailAddress)

]%%

%%[ if not empty(@InLondonUsers) then ]%%
(Content for London segment)
%%[ endif ]%%
```

**Reference:**
[AMPScript Lookup() Function](https://ampscript.guide/book/lookup)

> **Lookup(S1, S2, S3, S4)**
>
> Returns specified value from a data extension.
>
> *Arguments*
>
> S1 - The name of the data extension from which to return the specified
> value
>
> S2 - Name of column from which to return a value
>
> S3 - Name of column to match on to identify the row that contains the lookup value
>
> S4 - Value to match S3 against

There are other ways to retrieve data from Data Extensions.  You can find more code samples [here on my blog](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/).