# SFMC Dynamic Content with Content Builder - See if user in DE

Tags: email, email-template, dynamic, content-builder

I'm sending to multiple Data Extensions and I need content to dynamically populate based on whether or not an e-mail address is in a given Data Extension.

I created a paste HTML tempalte in Content Builder, inserted a Dynamic Content Block but when I go to set up the rules there isn't really one that works for what I'm trying to do. In a perfect world the rule would check to see if an e-mail address is present in a specific DE, if so, display the dynamic content. If not, display default content.

I found [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108828/sfmc-use-ampscript-to-see-if-user-is-in-data-extension) which shows it's possible with AMPScript. However I'm looking to see if it's posible using Dynamic Content in Content Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no supported way to do this in the `Dynamic Content` block in `Content Builder`, but there is a workaround:

Say you have DE1, DE2, and DE3. You can create an attribute in those DEs called (for instance) `DEName` and give it the value of 1 for all the email addresses on DE1, 2 for all the ones in DE2, etc. Make sure the value is also the default value, so that new subscribers get it by default.

Then in content builder, your rules in the dynamic block can be:

- rule 1: `DEName = 1` --> content: your content for DE1
- rule 2: `DEName = 1` --> content: your content for DE1
- rule 3: `DEName = 1` --> content: your content for DE1
- default: your default for other DEs

Notes:

- Please make sure you **test workarounds thoroughly** before doing real sends!
- The AMPScript option you mentioned is preferred.